# Sending username and password to localhost not working?

Tags: android, android-volley

This sends over the username and password of the registered account after it passes all the requirements. Must contain 1 lowercase, 1 uppercase, 1 number, and 1 special character, but for some reason the getParams() method is not working.. it says void result, but this is the exact code that is given in volley. What is wrong?

```
package com.example.eid.authenticator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import java.lang.Object;


public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.




        Button registerButton = findViewById(R.id.registerButton);


        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
                EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
                final String sUsername = username.getText().toString();
                final String sPassword = password.getText().toString();
                final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                final String url = "10.0.2.2";
                if(sUsername.matches("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter a username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(sPassword.matches("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter a password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else if(sPassword.matches("^([^0-9]*|[^A-Z]*|[^a-z]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password must contain letters and numbers and uppercase",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            else if(sPassword.length() < 6){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password must be greater than 6 characters",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                else {

                    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                                    mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
                        }
                    })

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("user",sUsername);
                        params.put("pass",sPassword);


                        return params;
                    }




                    Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, waitingPage.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is a screenshot of the error, it's a syntax one I believe, but I legitimately do not see it at all. It looks fine to me.

ERROR IMAGE

[image]

Comment: did you receive error message?

Comment: first of all show your error log

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat  I apologize I put a picture of the error on the original post. it's syntax related, it's embarassing, but i've been stuck for an hour on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

> You forget `{` after `})` before the getParams() and afetr the
>   getParams() `;`

```
final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                                mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", "Androidhive");
                params.put("email", "abc@androidhive.info");
                params.put("password", "password123");

                return params;
            }

        };
```

URL should be `http://10.0.2.2/folder_name/login.php`

Comment: I am an idiot thank you very much this was it... I feel so stupid.

Comment: @ItachiSan try this tutorial for further learning https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: can you explain what is folder_name in the URL?

Comment: @ItachiSan may be you are using wamp/xampp then in htdocs you have created folder and then file so need to write that foldner name if no folders then write direct file name

Comment: it is a flask server my partner created that is currently running on my localhost.

Comment: just add file name after that 10.0.2.2 address

Answer (score 0):

**GET** method never calls `getParams()` , if you need to pass params in **GET** you will need to pass it as url params,`getParams()` does get called in **POST** request, see below

Convert it to **post** request like this

```
 final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

Comment: `getParams()` is called only in post request, that might be your issue

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are using `GET`

> Request.Method.GET

It should be `POST` like

> Request.Method.POST

And you need to keep `getParams()` method inside of `{ };` like:

```
@Override
        public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error){
            mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
    }) {

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("user", sUsername);
        params.put("pass", sPassword);


        return params;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you that was a future error I would've ran into, but it doesn't solve the current syntactical issue i attatched a picture to the original post it might help.

Comment: Updated my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

And also change your URL to this: http://10.0.2.2/login.com

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void getRideStatus() {

    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Global.BASE_URL + Global.GET_RIDE_STATUS, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("AA", response);

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                if (obj.getString("code").equals("1")) {
                    alertDialog(API.rMessage(obj));
                    loader.dismiss();
                    waitTimer.cancel();
                }
                else if (obj.getString("code").equals("2")) {

                    loader.show();


 //                        dialog.setMessage(obj.getString("message"));
//                        alertDialog(API.rMessage(obj));
//                        loader.dismiss();
                } else if (obj.getString("code").equals("3")) {
                    loader.dismiss();
                    alertDialog(API.rMessage(obj));
 //                        setAlert("Normal");
                    waitTimer.cancel();
                } else if (obj.getString("code").equals("4")) {

                    loader.dismiss();
                    waitTimer.cancel();
                    setAlert("Normal");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            //Pass the parameters to according to the API.
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = Utils.getUserPreferences(HomeActivity.this, Global.RESPONSE_COUPON);
            CustomerCoupon obj = gson.fromJson(json, CustomerCoupon.class);
            params.put("user_token", Utils.getUser(HomeActivity.this).getUser_token());
            params.put("order_id", "");
            params.put("customer_latitude", String.valueOf(sourceLL.latitude));
            params.put("customer_longitude", "" + sourceLL.longitude);
            params.put("continue","");

            Log.e("AA", params.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```